# Opposite of jQuery .parents() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an userscript for a page. The page is old-school tables-everywhere design. I'm trying to access long table of fields so that they can be filled by script.

The structure can be simplified to be like this:

```
<form>
  <blockquote>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <table>
              <!-- THE DESIRED <input> FIELDS ARE HERE!! -->
           </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
               <!-- Contains <select> <input> -->
            </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- the table repeats and I need all inner tables -->
  </blockquote>
</form>
```

So I was thinking I could get aAll tables that are in `form table` but *do NOT contain* `<select>`.

I think oposite of the [parents selector in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) would be ideal. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
$('form table table').not(':has(select)');
```

`form table table` selects all tables that are in `form table`, then we excludes items that has a `select` element

Comment: Well done, it works!

Comment: Maybe even `$('form table table:not(:has(select))');` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form table table').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('select').size()==0){
     //do something
    }
 });
```

another way to do it.